# QGIS Print composer's Atlas export file options missing Tiff on Mac

Tags: qgis, print-composer, mac, atlas, apple

Trying to create a workflow using QGIS for tree canopy inventory projects that works in both Windows and Mac.
I do not have a Mac, but doing peer review is on Mac.

There seems to be an issue with the Print Composer's Atlas export image not having the option to select tiff for the export output.
Screen shots are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SdqD.png) and below.

Can anyone here with Mac verify the lack of export to tiff option or post screenshot of where the option is located?

[image: screenshots]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like http://hub.qgis.org/issues/12435. Given that it's > 2 years old it may be worth contacting your QGIS support provider and putting pressure on them to fix this.

Comment: Thank you for finding that. How does one add a comment hub.qgis ? I went to help and registration takes you to something called redmine.org ?